# Defining rules for the random pattern

Tags: java, nested-loops

I wrote this code to make 5x5 pattern which is consisting of random numbers.

```
  public class RandomPatternGenerator {
    public static final int n= 5;
    public static int boxArray[][] = new int[n][n];

public static int randomize(int randomNumber){

    randomNumber = (int)(Math.random()*5);
    return randomNumber;
}

public static void letsPattern(){   
 for(int x=0; x<5; x++){
        for (int y = 0; y<5; y++){
            boxArray[y][x]= randomize(x);
                }
            }
        }
public static void display(){
    for(int x=0; x<5; x++){
        for (int y = 0; y<5; y++){
        System.out.print(boxArray[y][x]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }   
  }
public static void main(String[] args){

letsPattern();
display();   }}
```

However i would like to define two rules: Two 4 can not be adjacent to each other horizontally. 
Also whenever there is a 3 in the pattern, there should be 0 above it.

How can i apply these two rules together?

Answer (score 0):

If you implement these two rules, then you should first note that your numbers will no longer truly be "random."  Assuming that's ok...

To implement the first rule (4 rule), you have to keep a `boolean` that tracks whether the previous number horizontally was a 4. If it is true AND your random number is another 4, then get another random number. Keep getting another number (hint: while loop) until it is no longer a 4.  Be sure that your `boolean` accurately tracks whether the previous number horizontally was a 4 (hint: you have to reset it every time).

To implement the second rule (3 rule), you have to go through your entire array twice. The first time you set it up as you currently do (including the 4 rule). The second time, you search through in order to find any 3s (hint: another 2 nested for loops). If this 3 is not on the top row, then replace the number above the 3 with a 0.

I'm opting not to give you any code that implements this, but I believe you can figure out how to do it from what I've provided.  Good luck!

PS: You define `n` as 5 (which I totally agree with), but then never use it! Every time you have a 5 in your code, it really should be an `n` both for consistency case and also so that you confuse yourself less later ("Why was this a 5 and not a 6?" sort of thing)

Answer (score 0):

For adjacent 4s you want to compare your current number to the previous number. If the number selected is a 4 and the previous is a 4 you need to get a new random number for the selected 4. 
For the 3, if your selected number is a 3 and you are not in the first row you just want to change the number above it to a 0.

```
public static void letsPattern() {  
for(int y=0; y<5; x++){
    for (int x = 0; x<5; y++){ 
        boxArray[x][y]= randomize();

        //4 rule
        if(x>=1 && y>=1) {
        bool adjacent = true;
        while(adjacent) {
           if(boxArray[x][y] == 4 && boxArray[x][y] == boxArray[x-1][y]) {
               boxArray[x][y] = randomize();
           } else {
               adjacent = false;
           }
        }

        //3-0 rule
        if(y>=1) {
            if(boxArray[x][y] == 3) {
                boxArray[x][y-1] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

I switched your for loops. Also there is not point in having a parameter for randomize() because you do not use it in the method.